# React native cannot render html

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render html from my array. Nothing show, just a blankspace - How can I render HTML in my component?

```
import React from "react";
import {
     View,
     Text,
     TouchableOpacity,
     StyleSheet,
     useWindowDimensions,
} from "react-native";

import HTML from "react-native-render-html";


const BannerWidget = () => {
     const contentWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
 
     const testArray = [
          {
               productType: "Package",
               status: "Included",
               productName: "Advanced",
               IsFreeProductRedeemed: false,
               PackageItems: ["xxx", "ccc"],
               freeText: "<p>sample <strong> FREE </strong> </p>",
          },
     ];
     
     return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
               <HTML
                    souce={{ html: testArray[0].freeText }}
                    contentWidth={contentWidth}
               />
          </View>
     );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
          flex: 1,
          padding: 10,
          color: "black",
     },
});

export default BannerWidget;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React Native docs currently recommend [React Native WebView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview). It would look something like below.

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: '<p>Here I am</p>' }}
/>
```

Just add the npm module to your project. Import the WebView and add your html as shown above.